# Swap partition showing unknown. Can I format it to ntfs or ext4 for keeping my files or this will cause problems to system? I don't need swap space

Tags: partitioning, swap

The gnome disk utility shows a partition with 3.1 GB is linux swap with unknown content. In a terminal running `free` command total swap shows `0`. What does this mean?

I don't need any swap space, so can I format this partition to ntfs or ext4 safely (without disturbing the system)?

[Edit]
I have encrypted `/home`. I have 3 GB RAM and I don't have to run any heavy application in Ubuntu so I don't need swap.

During installation, I allocated 13 GB to Ubuntu of which only 1.5 GB is left. .In Gnome disk utility it is showing 3.1 GB is linux swap but in gparted it is not recognized as linux swap (it just says unknown). So I want to just format it.

My question is: does deleting or formatting that partition cause any error? (If yes, then I will drop this option and increase my partition size instead.)

Comment: Did you encrypt /home? If so you will not see swap in many tools as it is just encrypted space.

Comment: do you have plenty of ram ? why you say you not need it ? are you really in need of 3.1 GB of space ? I am asking out of curiosity with honest intentions .

Comment: I formatted the drive via Gparted to ntfs. It created a new drive with that space (3GB) available. No idea what was that unknown space. But no errors and data loss. Rebooted safely.

Comment: Now i merged my ubuntu \ and the above 3 GB partition to get my home folder of 8.5 GB total space.YE!! Did it through gparted (via booting with bootable usb stick).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want swap anymore then swapoff the swap partition through gparted and then format it to ext4 or ntfs(whatever you want) for storing your datas.

For mine, the output of the `free` command is,

```
          total           used       free
Swap:     10501116          0      10501116
```

Which means, the total size of my swap partition is `10` GB, from that `0` space was used.

Comment: mine output shows total swap is 0 .

Comment: post your gparted screenshot.

Comment: cant post images here (10 reputation points needed) http://i.stack.imgur.com/EGZ77.png - may be this will work :)

Comment: upload it to imgur.com and post back the link here.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EGZ77.png

Comment: click gparted option on the menu bar and select refresh device option.

Comment: done that many times, should i format it to ntfs?

Comment: you can't format it because it contains red mark. Try to remove badblocks in that disk.

Comment: oops i formatted it to ntfs !! waiting for any error

Comment: Then merge it with your existing ext4 or ntfs partition.

Answer (score 1):

It's recommended to have the swap partition, anyway if you want to give it the correct format you can do it from shell commands with `mkswap /dev/sdax` where `a` stands for your disk and `x` stand for the partition number.

An easy way to turn of your swap partition is `swapoff`.